# patch django.conf settings does not mutate the value

Tags: python, django, mocking, patch, pytest-django

I have `VOUCHERED_PEOPLE` in the `base.py` And I need to test it by `dummy`
I have read [this](https://gist.github.com/blaix/2294982) in order to get `settings.VOUCHERED_PEOPLE` being patched, but it does not work in Django2

`utils.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
def get_voucher_people(mobile_phone: str) -> typing.Dict[str, typing.Union[str, int]]:
    """Read name from base.py"""
    for record in settings.VOUCHERED_PEOPLE:
        if record['mobile_phone'] == mobile_phone:
            return record
    return None
```

`base.py`

```
VOUCHERED_PEOPLE = [{...}, {...}]
```

`tests.py`

```
with patch('poinkbackend.apps.vouchers.utils.settings', VOUCHERED_PEOPLE=dummy):
    from pprint import pprint
    import ipdb;
    ipdb.set_trace()
    give_voucher(sarit.userprofile, True)
```

**Attempt1:**

```
with patch.object(settings, 'VOUCHERED_PEOPLE') as mock_settings:
    mock_settings.return_value = dummy
```

This does not work. `settings.VOUCHERED_PEOPLE` is a function. I have to execute it to get dummy by `settings.VOUCHERED_PEOPLE()`

**Problem:**
patch does not work. It is not change value to be my `dummy`

**Question:**
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a specific [context manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) for modifying settings in tests:

```
with self.settings(VOUCHERED_PEOPLE=dummy):
    ...
```

With pytest-django, you can [use `settings` as a fixture](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#settings) and modify it directly; it will be reverted at the end of each test.

```
def test_vouchered_people(settings):
    settings.VOUCHERED_PEOPLE=dummy
    ...
```

Comment: That's very cool! Next project I will use `UnitTest`. This time I am sorry. I forgot to mention I am using `pytest-django`. I just update my question. Thank you very much for fast response.